# there is an error when i download file with url on php

Tags: php, ajax, url, download

My codes work -- send variables from P.html to V.php with ajax

And there is an error when i put some code in V.php.

V.php makes span tag to P.html

When i use code that download file with url, ERROR(Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null // that i put data with htmlspecialchars from V.php to P.html)

But code that download file with url And V.php code are work well when it used by dividing.

what should i do with this .

When i delete this code

```
    curl_setopt($curlCh, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curlCh, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curlCh, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
```

There is no error but doesn't download file

This is an code that has error

```
....

    $query4 = "SELECT mongoFN FROM hashDB WHERE CarID = '".$var2."' AND Day = '".$var3."'";
    $result4 = mysqli_query($conn, $query4);
    $row4 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result4);
    $field4 = 'http://192.168.44.111:8081/api/file/download?filename='.$var2.$row4['mongoFN'].'.h264.mp4';
?>

<?php echo "<span id='a1' style='display:     none;'>".htmlspecialchars($field1)."</span>";?>
<?php echo "<span id='a2' style='display:     none;'>".htmlspecialchars($field2)."</span>";?>
<?php echo "<span id='a3' style='display:     none;'>".htmlspecialchars($field3)."</span>";?>
<?php echo "<span id='a4' style='display:     none;'>".htmlspecialchars($field4)."</span>";?>


//New code 
<?php
     $url =  'http://192.168.44.111:8081/api/file/download?filename=41b775820181005182638.h264.mp4';
    $curlCh = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curlCh, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curlCh, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curlCh, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
    $curlData = curl_exec ($curlCh);
    curl_close ($curlCh);

    $downloadPath = "/Users/mac_pc/Downloads/".$field4.".mp4";
    $file = fopen($downloadPath, "w+");
    fputs($file, $curlData);
    fclose($file);
?>
```

And These are works well

1.A.php (consist of only this code)

```
<?php
    $url =  'http://192.168.44.111:8081/api/file/download?filename=41b775820181005182638.h264.mp4';
    $curlCh = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curlCh, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curlCh, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curlCh, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
    $curlData = curl_exec ($curlCh);
    curl_close ($curlCh);
    $downloadPath = "/Users/mac_pc/Downloads/"mp.mp4";
    $file = fopen($downloadPath, "w+");
    fputs($file, $curlData);
    fclose($file);
?>
```

2. V.php ( No download file with url code)

   ....

   ```
        $query4 = "SELECT mongoFN FROM hashDB WHERE CarID = '".$var2."' AND Day = '".$var3."'";
        $result4 = mysqli_query($conn, $query4);
        $row4 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result4);
        $field4 = 'http://192.168.44.111:8081/api/file/download?filename='.$var2.$row4['mongoFN'].'.h264.mp4';
    ?>

    <?php echo "<span id='a1' style='display:     none;'>".htmlspecialchars($field1)."</span>";?>
    <?php echo "<span id='a2' style='display:     none;'>".htmlspecialchars($field2)."</span>";?>
    <?php echo "<span id='a3' style='display:     none;'>".htmlspecialchars($field3)."</span>";?>
    <?php echo "<span id='a4' style='display:     none;'>".htmlspecialchars($field4)."</span>";?>
   ```

Comment: I found that there is an same error when i add "echo shell_exec("java -jar test.jar");" under the query code($field4 ~~ )

Answer (score 0):

Because of a time delay . Sorry for it